# What is wrong this backbone.js code with an error "a._validate is not a function"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to develop a Todo-list application like a sample application for Backbone.js. The code is [here](http://github.com/naoty/todoapp) (prototype branch is the latest). When text is input, a task with the text should be  saved on local storage. But, the text failed to be saved with a below error.

> a._validate is not a function

Why? Codes is following.

app/assets/javascripts/tasks.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  tasks = new Todoapp.Collections.Tasks
  appView = new Todoapp.Views.AppView(el: $("#todoapp"), collection: tasks)
```

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/app.js.coffee

```
Todoapp.Views.AppView = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    "keypress #task_input" : "createTask"
  initialize: ->
    this.collection.bind("add", this.alertCreate, this)
  createTask: (e) ->
    text = $("#task_input").val()
    return if !text or e.keyCode isnt 13
    this.collection.create(content: text)
    $("#task_input").val("")
  alertCreate: ->
    alert("Created!")
```

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/collections/tasks.js.coffee

```
Todoapp.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: Todoapp.Models.Task
  localStorage: new Store("tasks")
```

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/task.js.coffee

```
Todoapp.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your model definition:

```
Todoapp.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend
```

All that does is assigns the `Backbone.Model.extend` method to `Todoapp.Models.Task`, it doesn't execute the `extend` method. Add some parentheses and it will work:

```
Todoapp.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ejjHz/

Or better, write your CoffeeScript in CoffeeScript rather than some mixture of CoffeeScript and JavaScript:

```
class Todoapp.Models.Task extends Backbone.Model

class Todoapp.Collections.Tasks extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Task
  localStorage: new Store('tasks')

class Todoapp.Views.AppView extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'keypress #task_input' : 'createTask'
  initialize: ->
    @collection.bind('add', @alertCreate)
  createTask: (e) ->
    text = $('#task_input').val()
    return if !text or e.keyCode isnt 13
    @collection.create(content: text)
    $('#task_input').val('')
  alertCreate: =>
    alert('Created!')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HPHVG/

The changes:

1. Use `class ... extends` instead of `C = B.extend`. This alone would solve your problem.
2. Use `@` instead of `this`.
3. Use bound methods (`=>`) instead of supplying a context to `bind`.

Comment: I like this answer. Just to add to it, if it's an underscore problem make sure that underscore.js is being loaded before backbone.js

Comment: @Luke: you'd get "undefined is not a function" problems when defining te classes f underscore wasn't loaded though. This is an "parentheses are optional except when they're not" problem.

Comment: Thank you! It has just worked!
I'm learning CoffeeScript with Backbone.js, and so your advice is very useful.